# Freiman-isomorphic sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Haw can we prove that an arbitrary set $A$ of $n$ positive integers is 2-Freiman isomorphic to a subset of {$ 1,2,...,4^{n}$}  and $4^{n}$ cannot be improved to $2^{n}$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an open conjecture from [a paper of Konyagin and myself](http://math.haifa.ac.il/seva/Papers/colifr.dvi) that every $n$-element set of integers is Freiman-isomorphic to a subset of $[0,2^{n-2}]$. There are some counterexamples for small values of $n$, but it is believed that the conjecture is "essentially true"; if so, your $4^n$ actually *can* be improved to $2^n$ (and in fact, to $2^{n-2}+1$). No further improvements are possible: the set $\{0,1,2,4,\dotsc,2^{n-2}\}$ is not isomorphic to any shorter integer set. (If it is isomorphic to a set $\{a_0,a_1,\dotsc, a_{n-1}\}$, then $a_0+a_2=2a_1$, $a_0+a_3=2a_2$, ... , $a_0+a_{n-1}=2a_{n-2}$; assuming without loss of generality $a_0=0$, this results in $a_i=2^{i-1}a_1$, so that the diameter of $\{a_0,a_1,\dotsc, a_{n-1}\}$ is $|a_{n-1}-a_0|\ge 2^{n-2}$.)

The bound $8^n$ (somewhat weaker than you indicated) can be obtained as follows.

It suffices to show that if $A\subseteq[0,l]$ is an $n$-element integer set not isomorphic to a set of diameter smaller than $l$, then $l<8^n$. Write $A=\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ and fix a prime $2l<p\le 4l$, so that $A$ is isomorphic to its image $A_p$ under the canonical homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

Consider the $n$-dimensional integer lattice $\Lambda:=(a_1,\dotsc, a_n)\Bbb Z+p\Bbb Z^n$. It is easily seen that the determinant of this lattice is $p^{n-1}$; hence, by [Minkowski's First Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem), $\Lambda$ has a non-zero point in the $n$-dimensional cube $[-p^{1-1/n},p^{1-1/n}]^n$. Consequently, there exist integers $y_1,\dotsc,y_n\in[-p^{1-1/n},p^{1-1/n}]$, not all equal to $0$, such that for yet another integer $z$ we have $y_i\equiv za_i\ (i\in[1,n])$. It is immediately seen that $z\not\equiv 0\pmod p$; hence, the set $\{y_1,\dotsc,y_n\}$ is isomorphic to $A_p$, and therefore to $A$. The assumption that $A$ is not isomorphic to a set of diameter smaller than $l$ implies now $2p^{1-1/n}\ge l$. Combining this with $p\le 4l$ yields the desired bound $l<8^n$.

For $l$ large, the prime $p$ can be chosen to satisfy $p=(2+o(1))l$, leading to $l<4^{(1+o(1))n}$. Much better estimates (something like $2^{(1+o(1))n}$, I believe) can be obtained using the method of the aforementioned paper; see also Chapter 20 of the monograph *Structural Additive Theory* by David Grynkiewicz.

Comment: I cannot find a proof in Chapter 20 of that book (it looks to complicated for me). The results are stated as exercises in the book "Sumsets and structure" of Rusza ( in the corect form), but I couldn't solve them.

Comment: (Sorry I have been stuck with some problems) Your proof is realy beautiful, and I think that the method is strong enough for obtaining the bound with 4 instead of 8: we have to chose a good prime p ( I think we can find a p smaller, I guess,  than 2l with a Freiman isomorphism like in Rusza's  Model Lemma).

Comment: If we chose p greater than rl we get a variant of the theorem for r-Freiman isomorphisms. Anyway thank for your help ( the paper mentioned is very interesting).

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: I am not sure I understand your concern. We do not need to consider the set $B_p$, just $B$. It is isomorphic to $A_p$ and, by transitivity of the isomorphism relation, to $A$. But any set isomorphic to $A$ has diameter at least $l$. Thus, the diameter of $B$ is at least $l$, whence $2p^{1-1/n}\ge l$. Does this answer the question?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: I think I see now what the problem is.  The reason that the two sums $y_i+y_j$ and $y_{i'}+y_{j'}$ are equal as integers is that the difference of these two sums is divisible by $p$ and *smaller than $p$ in absolute value*, as it follows from  $y_i\in[-p^{1-1/n},p^{1-1/n}]$.

Comment: aha, that makes sense entirely; thank you very much!!